# Is there something like ctrl + m + o for Xaml?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, resharper

I often miss <kbd>CTL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, that collapses all properties and methods in the code editor, when working with Xaml.

I installed [Xaml Regions](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3c534623-bb05-417f-afc0-c9e26bf0e177) and it is nice but I still miss <kbd>CTL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

I have played around with:

<kbd>CTL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>

<kbd>CTL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

<kbd>CTL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

<kbd>CTL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>

But none of them does what I want.

Is there an extension or even a built-in command that does what I want?

To clearify, I want all children of a resource file collapsed to one row for easier navigation like this:

[image]

Comment: I don't know of a single command, but `Ctrl+M, M` does the trick for me. If you want to collapse everything regardless of whether it's already collapsed, you can do `Ctrl+M, P` and then Outlining > Start Automatic Outlining to expand everything before toggling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently discovered you can use Ctrl+M, L even though it doesn't work directly. It just takes a little algorithm.

1. Press Ctrl+M, L.
2. If everything is expanded, press it again.
3. ???
4. Profit.

Pressing Ctrl+M, L expands everything if anything is collapsed, otherwise it collapses everything. So when you first open a file, pressing it once should be sufficient. If you've been collapsing and expanding some regions, pressing it once to expand and once to collapse works fine.

Answer (score 2):

This may be too off-topic, however using the VSVim add-on will emulate Vim, unifying a lot of [keyboard shortcuts](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Folding#Opening_and_closing_folds) for editing files:

> The command `zc` will close a fold (if the cursor is in an open fold), and `zo` will open a  fold (if the cursor is in a closed fold). It's easier to just use `za` which will toggle the  current fold (close it if it was open, or open it if it was closed).
>
> The commands `zc` (close), `zo` (open), and `za` (toggle) operate on one level of folding, at  the cursor. The commands `zC`, `zO` and `zA` are similar, but operate on all folding levels (for example, the cursor line may be in an open fold, which is inside another open fold; typing `zC` would close all folds at the cursor).
>
> The command `zr` reduces folding by opening one more level of folds throughout the whole buffer (the cursor position is not relevant). Use `zR` to open all folds.
>
> The command `zm` gives more folding by closing one more level of folds throughout the whole buffer. Use `zM` to close all folds.

**Edit:** Command sequence in this case would be `zM` then `zo`.